# Error after generating optimization profile

Tags: react-native, xcode9

I'm using Xcode 9 and was trying to solve provisioning issue. Which led me to generate optimization profile.

And the building process always ended with error :

> Could not read profile
>   /Users/louis/project/Scavenger/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata:
>   No such file or directory

[This is my build settings Apple LLVM - Code Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFXCA.png)

I already tried to clean the project and also delete the derived folder with `Shift` + `alt` + `command` + `K`.
Any idea of other approaches to try? Please help